# What are these electric components?

Tags: identification, schematics, diagram, hvac

This is a snapshot from a single-line diagram of emergency switchboard drawn in 1984 for an oil & gas project.

What are these two components next to the motor symbol? What could `CP` stand for? What is the rectangle with a black dot?

[image]

The `*` note states

> * -CONTROLS WIRED IN MULTICORE TO MARSHALLING COMPARTMENT.

Comment: Most diagrams come with a legend - which might answer most of your questions.

Comment: If there is such a legend diagram, it is sadly not accessible at the moment.

Comment: Did you get this from a book or manual?

Comment: The look of the box + dot kinda suggests an emergency stop button for an NVR switch. (Then, Could CP be a control panel, somewhere else, needing a remote stop for safety?)

Answer (score 1):

You need a legend from the drawing from the project plan package. The location of the box near the motor suggests that the symbol in question is a transducer that is monitoring the motor. It could be a thermocouple. The symbol could also designate a group of transducers such as motor winding temperature, shaft rotation, air flow. The designation CP likely means control panel.

Comment: If HVAC is of any importance it might be a room temperature sensor for the ventilation to work on.