# What kind of terminals are these?

Tags: identification, schematics, symbol

What are these symbol from single-line diagrams of switchboards?

[image]

It seems they are not always related to optical fiber, as shown on this snapshot:

[image]

Comment: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/586057/152903

Comment: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/586019/what-are-these-electric-components/586057#comment1533725_586019